# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory at runtime

Tags: java, websphere, slf4j

Added the following Jars into the classPath of the project :

slf4j-api-1.6.3.jar
slf4j-was.jar

And in the Java class:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myClass.class);
```

At run time i got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at com.ibm.beans.session.myClass.<clinit>(myClass.java:99)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:236)
... 130 more
```

Comment: Check your class path at runtime. If when you compile you use -cp switch you also need to do so at runtime

Comment: At runtime, am deploying it on websphere server, and i have no idea what is the problem is

Comment: @ EJP, i downloaded theJar as mentioned in the Answer u mentioned as duplicates, and that doesn't solve my issue

Comment: Any Solutions ?